# How do you adjust the 'margins' in the Premiere Pro program window?

Tags: premiere

How do you adjust the 'margins' in the Premiere Pro program window?

For example

[image]

there's clearly some kind of smaller black square within the black square, and that smaller black square represents margins… Not anything I put in there but there by default.

The text is getting cut off when it's outside of certain margins at the top left right and bottom.

So any text too high gets cut off at the top, any text too low gets cut off at the bottom… Any text too far to the left gets cut off on the left, and likewise any text too far to the right gets cut off on the right.

I'd like to remove or change those margins.

Any idea how?

I suppose I could work within them, but I'd be interested in being able to change them too.

**Added note**

My example is a simple demonstration of the issue i face. What you see there is not a whole project where it's not clear what is what. My example is an example that clearly demonstrates the problem. I am showing you that there's what appears to be a border there hiding any text. If I just made a blank project and did one textbox, then you'd see it gets cut off. (nothing to do with nesting that I see mentioned in one answer as a possibility)

Comment: related- https://forums.creativecow.net/thread/3/1010944

Comment: updated link to that related one.  https://creativecow.net/forums/thread/text-gets-cut-off/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibility #1: If there's not just black filled rectangles from the rectangle tool around your text, then it looks like you might have nested your text into a sequence with smaller dimensions. Find the text on your timeline and check if it is in a nest. If so, try:
1. Right-click on the nest in the timeline
2. Choose 'Reveal in Project' to find the nest in the Project panel
3. Right-click on the nest in the Project panel
4. Choose 'Sequence Settings'
5. Change the Video > Frame Size 'horizontal' and 'vertical' values to match the sequence you added the nested text to.

Possibility #2:
Another way you can achieve this effect is in the Effects controls panel for the text clip. If you were to scale the video down, it would have hard borders. Check that the video scale is at 100%. [image]

Comment: that makes no sense.. My example was a simple demonstration of the issue i face. What you see there is not a whole project where it's not clear what is what.  My example is an example that clearly demonstrates the problem. I am showing you that there's a border there hiding any text.  If  I just made a blank project and did one textbox, then you'd see it gets cut off. All this stuff you speak of about nesting and sequencing just doesn't apply at all.

Comment: That was just the way that I would have accidentally created this error in my workflow, but I've edited the answer to add another possible cause based on the information you've added here. There are many ways to achieve the same result in Premiere.

Comment: thanks that 'possibility 2', answers it.. The reason ,why I was making that mistake, is that when I write in a textbox, the video options are expanded in effect controls, but the text options remain collapsed, so the only scale option showing is the video one.. have to manually expand the text one and scroll, to see the text options.  https://i.imgur.com/fjz9wJT.png